# How to use a list of indices to partition a list of observed in PyMC3?

Tags: pymc3

I have a list of observed data **score** and a list of indices **ind**. Every element of **ind** is either 0, 1, or 2. **score** and **ind** have the same length, and **ind** partitions **score** into three sets: if **ind[i]** is k, then **score[i]** is in set k.

I would like to fit three normal distributions to the data, one normal for set 0, one normal for set 1, and one normal for set 2. My PyMC3 code to set up the model is:

```
with pm.Model(): 
    mean = pm.Uniform('mean', 0, 1, shape=3) 
    sd = pm.Uniform('sd', 0, 1, shape=3)
    mean_i = pm.Deterministic('mean_i', mean[ind])
    sd_i = pm.Deterministic('sd_i', sd[ind])
    obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu=mean_i, sd=sd_i, observed=score)
```

But **mean_i** seems to have the wrong shape: the traceplots show it to have three elements, rather than just a single element as I expected. And the expression **mean[ind]** looks wrong: how does PyMC3 know that it should use **ind** in a way that aligns it with **score**?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
with pm.Model(): 
    mean = pm.Uniform('mean', 0, 1, shape=3) 
    sd = pm.Uniform('sd', 0, 1, shape=3)
    obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu=mean[ind], sd=[ind], observed=score)
```

For future reference you can also ask questions [here](https://discourse.pymc.io/)